# Elasticsearch index migration

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch version 0.90 and I have tried to move data to elasticsearch version 2.x with the help of logstash, Data is moved but index mapping is not migrated properly, please suggest the solutions

Comment: How are you moving the data? Normally you would create a new index with mappings and repopulate that index

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have migrated data from elasticsearch 0.90 to elasticsearch 2.3, First I created index with mapping then move index data with help of logstash, I had to change facets query to aggregations in my code.